# Assets directory path not correctly parsed when using dynamic file name in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I can use the syntax described in the [docs](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/assets) to load an image in the assets directory when the filename is known:

```
<img src=“~/assets/image.png” />
```

Whenever I attempt to load the image dynamically this does not work:

```
<img :src=`~/assets/${imageName}.png` />
```

Results in an error `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/~/assets/image.png"`

How can the `~/assets` path be used with a dynamic filename in Nuxt 3? The Nuxt v2 docs suggest that `require()` should be used, but this is specific to webpack rather than Vite, and is thus not referenced in the v3 docs.

Edit: to clarify following the comment from @kissu I can not just move to `/public` as I do not want the assets to have their own routes (they are dynamically generated images).

Additionally, the code works if I swap `~/assets` to `../assets` but this is fragile as there are often subfolders involved and it will be difficult to determine how many levels to go up to get to root, hence the desire to use the built-in path with `~/assets`.

Comment: Forgot the syntax for that but you can probably search on vite's github/stackoverflow/google with "dynamic import vite" IMO.

Comment: @kissu that was my first approach and I have searched extensively, but can't seem to locate any reference to the `/~/assets` pattern so it may be specific to Nuxt?

Comment: It doesn't need to be specific to assets or does it? Search more generically IMO. Otherwise, try to move the file in the public directory maybe?

Comment: The public and assets directories do different things when it comes to routing; I can not just move it to public.